# SwiftUI transition on a view contain a List have stuttering animations

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

Below is a Minimum Reproducible example - you could literally copy and paste and run the code.

When you tap on the "Press me" button, and the nearby bus stops view pop up, the transition animation stuttering is very evident, especially when in the largest presentation detent.

Tested this on iOS 17.2 on iPhone 13 Pro Max

I have no idea how to fix this. Like why is the List rows stuttering for only having 20 views inside it?

```
enum SheetViews: Identifiable {
        var id: SheetViews {
            return self
        }
    
    case welcome
    case nearbyBusStops
}

@Observable
class SheetStackViewModel {
    var views: [SheetViews] = []
    var lastViewInStack: SheetViews = .welcome
    
    init() {
        views.append(.welcome)
    }
    
    func push(view: SheetViews) {
        views.append(view)
        lastViewInStack = views.last ?? .welcome
    }
    
    func pop() {
        views.removeLast()
        lastViewInStack = views.last ?? .welcome
    }
    
    func index(for view: SheetViews) -> Int {
        return views.firstIndex(of: view) ?? 0
    }
}

struct BusStop: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
    
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = true
    
    @State private var sheetStackViewModel = SheetStackViewModel()
    
    @State private var annotations: [BusStop] = []
    var body: some View {
        Map() {
            ForEach(annotations) { annotation in
                Annotation("", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: annotation.latitude, longitude: annotation.longitude)) {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: sheetStackViewModel.lastViewInStack) { oldValue, newValue in
            if oldValue == .welcome && newValue == .nearbyBusStops {
                addAnnotations()
            } else if oldValue == .nearbyBusStops && newValue == .welcome {
                annotations.removeAll()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            GeometryReader { sheetGeo in
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(sheetStackViewModel.views) { view in
                        SheetView(view: view)
                    }
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
                .animation(.default.speed(1.2), value: sheetStackViewModel.lastViewInStack)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
            .presentationDetents([.height(200), .medium, .large])
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            .presentationBackground(.thickMaterial)
            .presentationCornerRadius(20)
            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            .interactiveDismissDisabled()
        }
        .environment(sheetStackViewModel)
    }
    
    //Add Test annotations
    func addAnnotations() {
        //Apple Park places
        let busStop1 = BusStop(latitude: 37.334886, longitude: -122.008988)
        let busStop2 = BusStop(latitude: 37.332832, longitude: -122.005365)
        let busStop3 = BusStop(latitude: 37.336958, longitude: -122.012988)
        let busStop4 = BusStop(latitude: 37.330894, longitude: -122.007463)
        let busStop5 = BusStop(latitude: 37.330082, longitude: -122.009793)

//Adding the same 5 annotations twice just to simulate more places on map
        annotations.append(busStop1)
        annotations.append(busStop2)
        annotations.append(busStop3)
        annotations.append(busStop4)
        annotations.append(busStop5)
annotations.append(busStop1)
        annotations.append(busStop2)
        annotations.append(busStop3)
        annotations.append(busStop4)
        annotations.append(busStop5)
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    let view: SheetViews
    @Environment(SheetStackViewModel.self) var sheetStackViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            switch view {
            case .welcome:
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Nearby Bus Stops") {
                            sheetStackViewModel.push(view: .nearbyBusStops)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            case .nearbyBusStops:
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Nearby Stops")
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button {
                            sheetStackViewModel.pop()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Go Back")
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    
                    List {
                        ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                                .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
                    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                }
            }
        }
        .opacity(view == sheetStackViewModel.lastViewInStack ? 1 : 0)
        .zIndex(Double(sheetStackViewModel.index(for: view)))
    }
}
```